# php prepared statement won't update or insert whole data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I have a page that my members can publish a new post or update the post. I got the the post content from tinymce editor. Everything works fine but when my content involes new line(s) or free spaces like `<p>&nbsp;</p>` or `<div>&nbsp;</div>`, it causes a problem. php-prepared statement only save the content before these tags not whole content. For example,

```html
<div><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div>
```

It saves or updates only this part:

```html
<div><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

And this is the my php-prepared statement php code:

```php
function createNewPost($post){

$cmd = "INSERT INTO posts(post_title,post_content,post_author,post_category,post_date,post_status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$mysqli = connectDB();
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($cmd);
$stmt->bind_param("ssiiss",$post["title"],$post["content"],$post["author"],$post["category"],$post["date"],$post["status"]);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->affected_rows;
$stmt->close();

if($count > 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

I suppose that the problem is "&" character. When prepare function reads that char, it might see it is dangerous and clear all html code after that part and returns to me the before `<p>&nbsp;</p>` part ?

```php
$post["content"] // I checked this variable.It has the whole content.
```

### Is there any suggestion ? Or am i doing it wrong ?

Edit: I forget to mention I am sending those datas via jquery post method even the data type is "text" and ajax-url get the whole text it again cuts off after "&" char.

jQuery Code:

```js
$('#submitPost').click(function(){

  var str = $('#postForm').serialize();
      str += "&editorContent=" + tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() + "&postDate=" + $('#labelDate').html();
      str += "&postID=" + "<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>";

  $.post("ajax-update-post.php", str,
                            function(data){
                                        $('#submitPost').attr("disabled",false);
                                        $('#submitPost').html("Update");
                                        $('#info').html(data);
                                        $('#info').slideDown("slow");
                                        //setTimeout(function(){ $('#info').slideUp("slow"); }, 3000);
                            },"text"
                            );
```

I solved my problem by changing the getting value of tinymce. I html data in jquery to another textarea and then getting serialize from new textarea.

Comment: both of these integers? `$post["author"],$post["category"]`

Comment: yes they are integers

Comment: see if there are any errors. Replace the `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` might not be, but worth checking

Comment: There is no mysql error and still inserting or updating like i said

Comment: Try using `htmlentities()` against the said variable(s) http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php and make sure the columns are long enough.

Comment: in mysql i save it with text type i will try the htmlentities function

Comment: check the amount of characters allowed for the column name post_content. or use data type TEXT without char limits and set charset to utf-8?

Comment: Yes I defined the data type just like you and it is UTF-8.

Comment: When you do `echo gettype($_post["author"]);` and `echo gettype($_post["category"]);` does it return integer?

Comment: Don't fix yourself to the `&`. If it were the problem the `<div>` in front of ot would be saved to the database. But it isn't, the text is cut off before at the line break. Line breaks are no problem for MySQL, so I'd start with disabling TinyMCE to see if the problem lies there.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thank you. I reconfigure the tinymce the problem was there.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function in php before inserting the actual data to the database

```
$sample = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>the string to be inserted</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
```

then if you want to decode that data use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($sample);
```

or you may try to use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) before inserting string html and [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) for decoding it.

Example

```
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
```

so in your case try to play with it.

```
$cmd = "INSERT INTO posts(post_title,post_content,post_author,post_category,post_date,post_status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$mysqli = connectDB();
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($cmd);

$content = htmlentities($post["content"]);

$stmt->bind_param("ssiiss",$post["title"],$content,$post["author"],$post["category"],$post["date"],$post["status"]);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->affected_rows;
$stmt->close();

//try to echo it out
echo $post["content"]."<br/>";

echo $content;

if($count > 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: I tried this method It gives the same result I dont understand there is something wrong but at the same time the method i used is correct.

Comment: so you did use htmlspecialchars or htmlentities before saving?I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: I tried the function almost everywhere the problem is that function that cuts off document after "&"

Comment: i think its about your javascript processing before it became part of $_POST